# How can I invert all the display colors in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, laptop, display

**How can I invert all the screen display colors in Windows Vista?**

The majority of my screen is white and I would prefer it the other way round.

The closest I could get is using High Contrast [Left-Alt + Left Shift + PrntScrn], but it doesn't quite work how I expect; the Windows features are mostly made black, but for example web pages still load in their original color, which again, is mostly white.

Is there a way I can just make the colors invert on the whole screen on a laptop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm)** is the solution (not free though)

Right click the PowerStrip tray icon and select **Color** > **Configure**.

Check the **Invert Gamma Ramp** (negative image) box.  If **Write Directly to Palette DAC** is not enabled, check that as well.

Optional: tweak the brightness, contrast, gamma, and temperature of the global colors or of the different components.

Comment: if it would have just been free :(

Comment: it's shareware, try before you buy. Inversion is only a gimmick, the program does far more than that. :)

Comment: It does do a lot more, but is sort of overkill for just this one function. However, I don't know if there is another option.

Answer (score 8):

I recently asked myself the same question: "how can I invert my screen's colors easily" (on Windows 7) and I was so disappointed to find there was no solution except the Magnifier trick, that I developed my own.

NegativeScreen  is a simple but complete program written in C# (sources open).

You can try it out [here](http://arcanesanctum.net/negativescreen/).

Comment: This is now my daily application. I am even considering compiling it for ARM on my Surface RT.

Comment: @Aphelion: Can you upload and share the ARM-compatible version if it works after jailbreaking the Surface RT?

Comment: @Yaurthek, thanks for your work. I noticed you said your app doesn't work on XP.  F.lux and redshift do work on XP, so I guess it is possible to invert the screen on XP also.  Here's a relevant link:  http://jonls.dk/2010/09/windows-gamma-adjustments/  Perhaps you could try that technique with NegativeScreen?  There's a demo app here:  http://www.nirsoft.net/vc/change_screen_brightness.html  I wanted to write a shorter demo but my windows build env is broken and I don't have time to fix it right now!

Answer (score 3):

Just to explain: all browsers will render web pages in the colours specified by the page author - unless you override this.

Johannes has explained where the option is in IE.

In Firefox it's at Tools > Content > Colours > Allow pages to choose their own colours, instead of my selection above.

Uncheck this option and set the text and background colours you like.

I can't seem to find the equivalent option in Google Chrome.

Comment: I fear, though, that the browser is just one example of things where it doesn't quite work.

Comment: from the answers, i dont think that there is an application that can do what I want :(

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For web pages you can usually set custom colors in your browser. In IE you can find this in Internet Options > General > Colors.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Windows Magnifier, set to 1x magnification, with invert enabled.

Comment: Yes, the simple way, I hope he has some steel-eyes :D

Comment: that does it for only half of the screen :(

Comment: eSKay: You can resize it using the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome has a high contrast extension that inverts colors on most text things on web pages while maintaining appropriate colors on most pictures and things. I use it constantly.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/high-contrast/djcfdncoelnlbldjfhinnjlhdjlikmph?hl=en