# Is there any way to change a specific window's colors?

Tags: windows-7, windows, colors, window-manager

I'd like to find a way to manipulate window colors: invert, tint, change brightness and contrast of specific windows in Windows 7 (although I'm interested in solutions for 8 and 10 as well).

Among the built-in tools there is only an inversion ability of *Magnifying Glass* (Winkey+Plus) and video card's control panel options which affect the entire screen. I know there is window opacity coz I've been playing with form properties in Visual Studio before, so maybe there's something for changing window colors too. Perhaps *Windows Desktop Manager* has some API command that does it?

*Clarification:* I'm not interested in theming windows or what's it called that you can do via Personalization options. I'm talking about affecting the color of the window's contents.

Answer (score -2):

Go to your desktop, right click then click on personalize. You can change the color of your windows and task bars from there.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP want's to change **specific** windows not all windows.

Comment: There is currently no way to change specific windows (that i know of) unless you want to download a third party application that will do it for you.

Answer (score -2):

I really doubt that this is possible.  You could use something like [**Windows Blinds**](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/), which does allow different skins on different applications.

Comment: I'm not interested in skins, I want to change the colors of the entire window including its rendered contents.

Comment: @user1306322 Well I have never used it, but I think that it has skins that are very much the same as the standard Aero theme.

Comment: Are you even reading what I'm saying? I'm not interested in the window border theming part at all!